# unabl to downlaod attachment inside webview expo its loading nothing downloads in mobile

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app, webview2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWHMB.png)I am the developer of React Native Expo WebView. I have tried a lot to download an attachment from the target website in WebView. If I run it in Chrome on my mobile, then the attachment is downloaded there. But if I go to the URL in WebView and download it, then it is not downloading. Kindly please see my [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v0AK.jpg) source code.